# how to get default values from a J-query Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am not getting the default values what i have mentioned in the plugin . It is accepting the used given values only.

```
 $.fn.mystyle = function( options ) {
    // default value 
    var defaults={
        textColor : "yellow" ,
        textDeco : "underline",
        backColor : "red",
        fontSize : 19
    };

    // assigning to a variable 
    var setting = $.extend( {} , $.fn.mystyle.defaults , options );

    // returing the value   
    return this.css({
        color : setting.textColor,
        backgroundColor : setting.backColor,
        textDecoration : setting.textDeco,
        fontSize : setting.fontSize
    }); 

};

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("p").mystyle({
            textColor: "orange",
        });
    });
```

Please visit http://jsfiddle.net/somsekhardash/Mx8jD/ for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the way you have used the defaults.

You have a local variable called `defaults` which is holding the default settings object, but when you are trying to merge the user options with the default one you are using a different object reference `$.fn.mystyle.defaults` which will have the value as `undefined`

The solution is to define your default object as

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.mystyle = function (options) {
        // default value 

        // assigning to a variable 
        var setting = $.extend({}, $.fn.mystyle.defaults, options);

        // returing the value   
        return this.css({
            color: setting.textColor,
            backgroundColor: setting.backColor,
            textDecoration: setting.textDeco,
            fontSize: setting.fontSize
        });
    };

    $.fn.mystyle.defaults = {
        textColor: "yellow",
        textDeco: "underline",
        backColor: "red",
        fontSize: 19
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3KjNQ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var setting = $.extend( {} , defaults , options );
```